# File opencv_core310.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check

Tags: c#, opencv, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have developed UWP desktop application using OpenCV nuget packages. All is working fine even in release mode. But the certification is failing by following errors:

```
File opencv_core310.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
File opencv_imgproc310.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
File opencv_video310.dll has failed the AppContainerCheck check.
```

Please help me if you have some pointers related to this type of issues.

I have enabled 'Native Tool chain' option.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1253

Answer (score 0):

Are you building these yourself, or are they pre-built binaries? If you are building yourself, just [use the `/APPCONTAINER` linker flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/appcontainer-windows-store-app?view=vs-2019).